# Restful - bad API design?

Tags: python, rest, python-requests

I got documentation for API I need to do integration. But some methods look weird.
For example:

```
 https://someurl.com/someurlxml.php post
```

`action - FindProduct`

paremeters:

`id = ProductId`

Logically it looks to me as it is `get` method, not `post`, because it only returns content and does not create anything (as a matter of fact, for some reason all methods there are `post` type even if logically they are not).

If I try for example:

```
s = requests.Session()
url = 'someurl.com/someurlxml.php'
```

And then if I do this:

`product = s.get(url, data={'action': 'FindProduct', 'id': 10})`

It does not return anything. But if I try:

`product = s.post(url, data={'action': 'FindProduct', 'id': 10})`

Then it returns the content of the product. But isn't it bad design of the API? Cause it looks like it should be `get` method, not post, isn't it? Should it really be `post`, not `get`?

So that API got me confused cause it's hard to guess what to expect when calling one or the other action. Or am I missing something here?

Answer (score 1):

From a purist point of view, you are correct; it should use GET not POST.

However many APIs use POST for everything because (a) GET is length-limited and (b) some methods like DEL are not widely supported.

In the end it isn't something you can control; it is POST, live with it.